# Setting form action value to a url

Tags: html, css, forms

I looking to setting form action value to a url to review info submitted by your form to a server.  I want this url "http://community.seidenberg.pace.edu:8080/demo/echo" to recieve the data submitted in the html page and show the results.  Can I have some help in this and where this form code would go on the html page or do I need a php page?

Here is the code for the html page (of course I would like the submit button to do all this.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<ol align="left">
    Full name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>

</ol>

<ol align="left">
    <input type="checkbox">Four 25-watt light bulbs for $2.39<br>
<input type="checkbox">Eight 25-watt light bulbs for $4.29<br>
<input type="checkbox">Four 25-watt long-life light bulbs for $3.95<br>
<input type="checkbox">Eight 25-watt long-life light bulbs for $7.49<br>
</ol>

<ol align="left">
<input type="radio" name="answer">Visa<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer">Master Card<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer">Discover<br>
</ol>


<p align="center">
<input type="submit" value="Submit Order">
<input type="reset" value="Clear Order Form">
</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to put everything in a form tag and supply the url link.

```
<form action="http://url">
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to put all your input fields into a `<form>` tag, so that they get sent to the server....

look at [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) to see, how forms work in HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<form action="/demo/echo">
<ol align="left">
    Full name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>

</ol>

<ol align="left">
    <input type="checkbox">Four 25-watt light bulbs for $2.39<br>
<input type="checkbox">Eight 25-watt light bulbs for $4.29<br>
<input type="checkbox">Four 25-watt long-life light bulbs for $3.95<br>
<input type="checkbox">Eight 25-watt long-life light bulbs for $7.49<br>
</ol>

<ol align="left">
<input type="radio" name="answer">Visa<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer">Master Card<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer">Discover<br>
</ol>


<p align="center">
<input type="submit" value="Submit Order">
<input type="reset" value="Clear Order Form">
</p>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```